# Tools for setting up Proxy Chain

Tags: proxy, chaining

We are trying to setup a chain of proxy server in our development system. We wanted to connect to a service through these proxies. The reason why we thought about `proxy chaining` is that there is no connectivity to the service from all the systems. So we thought we will run a proxy on one system, which will connect to a proxy on another system and so on.

```
Client ---> A (Proxy)--->B(proxy)---->Final destination
```

Could you please suggest some tools to achieve this? The service that we have is a SOAP based `secured` web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open source application called ProxyChain for this, here is readme file for this project:
http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/howto.html

You can install as more as proxy chains you want using this open source software, you can configure it per your requirements. Also you can somehow use some port-forwarding. What is the client for SOAP requests? Is it a web or desktop application?

Comment: client is a web application

Comment: Is this supported for Windows? Ours is windows platform

Comment: ProxyChains runs on Linux, so Proxy servers are Windows too?

Comment: what type of proxy are you looking for SOCKS or HTTP? Could you use some VPN?

Comment: Yes, Proxy servers are windows machines. I'm not sure if it is SOCK or HTTP. But in web services uses HTTP protocols.

Comment: You should do port forwarding here. There is a lot of softwares for port forwarding, just google it. You should do something like this, SOCKS server runs on B part of your schema, in A part you just run a port forwarder which will listen on a port and will forward all incoming data to your SOCKS server running in B. So A will be a just a relay and a port forwarder. Find a port forwarder software and it will just solve your problem together with a SOCKS server on B part

Comment: Thanks Vahid. Should this be a SOCKS server on B? Can this be an HTTP Proxy server itself?

Comment: Yeah, that could be SOCKS or HTTP, no difference. If you set SOCKS, you should set SOCKS option in your client, if you do HTTP, then it should be HTTP as proxy type in your client.

Comment: If you need help on finding port forward let me know, otherwise you can close this question. Regards